# Editable Content Table Cells in Azure DevOps Wiki Page

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

I know Azure DevOps Wiki pages has the insert table button to create a table, but I'm wondering if there is simple HTML to make the content editable in the table cell so I can enter a value and have it saved, like Jira can do without having to click the edit button every time, and go through the obnoxious text to add a new value to a table cell every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if there is simple html to make the content editable in the table cell
> so I can enter a value and have it saved, like Jira can do **without**
> having to click the **edit** button every time.

For this feature, I am afraid this is currently not supported in azure devops. If we want to modify the wiki, we need to click the edit button.

Until now, in our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there has been a such [suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/996773/why-we-cant-createedit-table-in-wiki-using-the-ui.html) exist in it. You can comment and vote it there. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. You can also submit a new [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and resources, I will comment and vote the previously submitted request.